# Changing Background color on Cell outside of view

Tags: swift3, ios10, uitableview, xcode8

I found an error with my code recently, and after doing everything I could think of to trouble shoot it, I was able to figure out what I believe to be happening. In my app, I have it changing the background color if a user selects that cell, this way you can have multiple cells selected. But if the first cell is selected it will deselect (change the background color) of all the other ones. But it turns out I get the following error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

when I try to change the background color of a cell that isn't visible on the screen. I'm assuming this is because only the visible cells are loaded in memory and all the others will only get loaded when they are visible again.

So How would I manually load a cell that I know the IndexPath for but also know it is outside of the view. Also, is there a way to know if cell at an IndexPath is loaded or not?

Here is my current code.

```
func selectAnyList(tableView: UITableView) {

    let sections = frc!.sections!
    let currentSection = sections[0]
    let numRows = currentSection.numberOfObjects

    for i in 0...(numRows - 1) {
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: i, section: 0)

        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! ItemListTVCell   //This is where the error happens if the cell is not visible
        if (i == 0) {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.activeAqua.withAlphaComponent(0.85)
        } else {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.85)
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Adding how cell is loaded

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let list: Ent_Lists = frc!.object(at: indexPath)
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "itemListCell", for: indexPath) as! ItemListTVCell

    if (list == Ent_Lists.anyList) {
        self.anyCell = cell
    }

    cell.listName.text = list.name
    cell.listImage.image = list.image!.uiImage

    if ((indexPath as NSIndexPath).row != 0 && listSet!.contains(list)) {
        numLists += 1
    }

    return cell
}
```

Edit2: Added Image of Ent_List in Coredata.
[image]

Comment: do you have an array of some models what you display in your list? If yes, add an extra property called bgColor, and update that.

Comment: I'm still a pretty green programmer, I'm not sure I understand your recommendation.

Comment: can you show how `Ent_Lists` looks like?

Comment: added an image of `Ent_Lists` from Coredata

Comment: do you always want to have a different bg color for the first cell's? Or it could be any cell what bg color should be different from the other?

Comment: Its always the first cell. And its not so much that the first is a different color than the rest, its that if you select the first it will automatically deselect anything other. But if you select any other the first gets deselected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a small sample file, where you can dynamically set the background color, and every time the one you select will have a different bg color.

```
import UIKit

// This is your core data entity
struct Entity {
    let title: String
}

// This is a basic viewModel, holding the selected property and the core data entity
class EntityViewModel {
    let entity: Entity
    // Set the selected property to false
    var selected: Bool = false

    init(entity: Entity) {
        self.entity = entity
    }
}

class TableViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    lazy  fileprivate var entityViewModels: [EntityViewModel] = self.makeEntityViewModels(count: 20)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self

    }
}

extension TableViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return entityViewModels.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")!
        // Work with viewModels, instead of the CoreData entities directly
        let viewModel = entityViewModels[indexPath.row]
        // Set the title of the cell
        cell.textLabel?.text = viewModel.entity.title
        // Based on the selected property, set the background color
        cell.backgroundColor = viewModel.selected ? .black : .yellow
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // Reset the selection for all viewModels
        entityViewModels.forEach { 
            $0.selected = false
        }

        // Get the viewModel at the right indexPath
        let viewModel = entityViewModels[indexPath.row]
        // Set its selected state to true
        viewModel.selected = true
        // Reload the tableView -> this will trigger `cellForRowAt`, and your background colors will be up to date
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

extension TableViewController {
    // This is where you read up from core data
    private func makeEntities(count: Int) -> [Entity] {
        var entities: [Entity]  = []
        for index in 0..<count {
            entities.append(Entity(title: "\(index) Some title"))
        }
        return entities
    }
    // Just wrap the core data objects into viewModels
    func makeEntityViewModels(count: Int) -> [EntityViewModel] {
        let entities = makeEntities(count: count)
        var viewModels: [EntityViewModel] = []
        for (index, entity) in entities.enumerated() {
            let viewModel = EntityViewModel(entity: entity)
            // Intialy, set the first viewModel to selected
            if index == 0 {
                viewModel.selected = true
            }
            viewModels.append(viewModel)
        }
        return viewModels
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will give this a try

Comment: @JasonBrady I have modified the `makeEntityViewModels ` function, so the first item will be selected upon setting up the viewModels.

Comment: Thank you again. I'm at work now, so I'll try this evening.